# How can I get rid of a screensaver on Lubuntu 20.04, using CLI?

Tags: lubuntu, configuration, screensaver

I have some VMs using Lubuntu. On restoring snapshot screensaver is always appearing which is both irritating and serving no purpose whatsoever.

How can I remove them via CLI? I want CLI as I plan to add it to script setting up initial VM.

Comment: It must be that when you took the snapshot the screensaver was there. Take another snapshot

Comment: Remove or disable?   The package `xscreensaver` is used to lock the session, so if it's removed you'll break your capacity to lock a logged in session.   (for more details look at my answer [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/question-regarding-xscreensaver-process/2998/3?u=guiverc)) but note *xscreensaver config is just a text file so editing it is pretty easy*

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Nope. The problem is that VM wakes up and after second or two it detects long time of inactivity and enables screensaver.

Comment: @guiverc I would be fine with either, as long as it is not appearing. In this case locking session does not matter but I would like to preserve this option to make it more general.

Comment: @guiverc On the main computer I have `~/.xscreensaver` config file. But on fresh install, with screensaver enabled it is not present. I guess I will need to prepare some `~/.xscreensaver` without any screen savers enabled.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a install to *play* with (ie. *test/change for answers; what I normally do; I booted various QA boxes & none have Lubuntu on them*).  I don't expect to do another QA-test install before my Friday (*at earliest*) so I'm unlikely to respond until at least then..